# python-socketio websocket emit to particular client in Socket.IO an ionic application

Tags: django, ionic-framework, websocket, socket.io, python-socketio

In my project I am using a Django application that acts as a SocketIO server to the Ionic mobile application which uses Socket.io to connect to the server as a client. My django application has another socket connection and it acts as a client to another micro service in python which uses python-socketio to create a websocket server. When I send a request from the Ionic application, it reaches the Django server which sends the request to the client via Django signals and then the request is sent to the micro services and the response from them are to be sent to the same Ionic application via Django. I was able to do it successfully when the Ionic application is only one. When there are multiple Ionic clients and when the data is different for them both, this does not make an effect. Both the clients receive the same data. My requirement forces me to have the communication through the Django server. Can anyone help me with this?

Microservice (python-socketio) <--> Django (python-socketio) <--> Ionic application (socket.io)
The communication is by websockets by eventlet.

Comment: Pass some of code so maybe we could do small esits and solve your problem

Comment: We have used socketio rooms to solve the problem. Adding for future reference to people with the same need.